# How to use WHERE and LEFT JOIN together in TypeORM?

Tags: typeorm

Consider two entities - > **Documents and Folder**.

Every Document has one folder, So the Document table has a foreign key to Folder Table.

I can check which documents have a folder in raw SQL but what would be the best way to do it in TypeORM?

I ran the following query. It runs fine but is there any better way?

```
const orphanDocuments = getRepository(Document).createQueryBuilder('document')
.where('document."folderId" IS NULL').getMany()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do:

```js
import {IsNull} from "typeorm";

const orphanDocuments = await getRepository(Document).find({
  where: folderId: IsNull()
})
```

Take a look at [FindOptions](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options)

Comment: Any way to do this using `queryBuilder` ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?